# unix script to replicate .net code logic

Tags: unix, filesystems

I do not have any experience with Unix coding besides navigating through directories and was wondering if someone could help me with writing a script to replicate what I am doing within .NET. I was told it would run faster since the .NET code is deployed remotely and sometimes using a mapped drive to access large amounts of folders runs slow. I basically am sorting files by moving files from selected folders to a group of folders based on the filename and sorting each based on the file date which is included in the filename.

```
    Private Sub moveAllfiles(ByVal directoryStuff As String)

    Dim templist As New ArrayList
    Dim finalDestination As String = String.Empty
    Dim pathName As String = String.Empty
    Dim fileToDelete As String = String.Empty
    Dim folderDate As String = String.Empty


    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim folders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directoryStuff)

    For Each item In folders
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(item)
        //' if directory is empty delete folder
        If Directory.GetFiles(item).Count = 0 Then
            Directory.Delete(item)
            Continue For
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To files.Count - 1
            Try
                counter += 1
                Dim oInfo As New FileInfo(files(i))
                // ' if file is empty or small delete it
                If oInfo.Length <= 1 Then
                    File.Delete(files(i))
                    Continue For
                End If
               If Not files(i).EndsWith(".gz") Then
                    CompressFiles(files(i))
                    Continue For
                End If
                Dim objInfo As New FileInfo(files(i))
                If Not objInfo.Name.Contains("Data_G_E") Then
                    If objInfo.Name.Contains("Data_G_P") Then
                        Dim pfiledate As String = objInfo.Name.Remove(20) 
                        pfiledate = pfiledate.Remove(7, 5)
                        Dim ftempDirectory As String 
                        = "M:\Archive\DataP\" + pfiledate & "\"
                        If Not Directory.Exists(ftempDirectory) Then
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(ftempDirectory)
                            Dim destdirectory As String = ftempDirectory
                            Dim ff As String = files(i)
                            fileToDelete = ff
                            File.Move(ff, destdirectory + objInfo.Name)
                            File.Delete(ff)
                        Else
                            Dim destdirectory As String = ftempDirectory
                            Dim ff As String = files(i)
                            fileToDelete = ff
                            File.Move(ff, destdirectory + objInfo.Name)
                            File.Delete(ff)
                        End If
                    End If
                    Continue For
                End If
                Dim filedate As String = objInfo.Name.Remove(20) 
                filedate = filedate.Remove(7, 5)
                Dim tempDirectory As String = String.Empty
                tempDirectory = "M:\Archive\DataE\" + filedate & "\"
                If Not Directory.Exists(tempDirectory) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory)
                    Dim destdirectory As String = tempDirectory
                    Dim ff As String = files(i)
                    fileToDelete = ff
                    File.Move(ff, destdirectory + objInfo.Name)
                    File.Delete(ff)
                Else
                    Dim destdirectory As String = tempDirectory
                    Dim ff As String = files(i)
                    fileToDelete = ff
                    File.Move(ff, destdirectory + objInfo.Name)
                    File.Delete(ff)
                End If
           Catch ex As Exception
                If ex.Message.Contains("already exists") Then
                    File.Delete(fileToDelete)
                    Console.WriteLine("DELETING OLD FILE " & fileToDelete)
                End If
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next


    Next

End Sub
```

Not sure if the logic makes sense but basically it searches all subfolders for files. Strips the filename to get the date and name which indicates where the file should go. Use the date to create a folder in the destination directory and move files accordingly. If someone can help get started or propose a better way to do this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not looking too closely (indeed, hardly at all) at your .NET code, it looks like you want to find all of the files in or below a given directory, extract a string from a fixed position in the filename to use as a destination directory, and then move each file to that directory.  If that is indeed what you are trying to do, it is fairly simple.  To move each file in or below the directory `/p/a/t/h` to `/path2/xxx` where xxx is taken from positions 7 to 10 in the file name (I selected the indexes 7 and 10 randomly), just do:

```
find /p/a/t/h -type f -exec sh -c 'd="/path2/${0:7:3}";
    mkdir -p "$d"; mv -i "$0" "$d"' {} \;
```

The `-i` flag to `mv` will cause an interactive prompt if you are overwriting any files, and is here as a safety catch to help prevent the unwary from blowing away files.  (But you, the reader, would never execute any code that you don't fully understand, so this is not necessary!)  You may want to replace it with a `-f` or just remove it.  Also note that the double quotes are only necessary if your filenames are pathological.  (For example, if they contain whitespace.)